# In a Unixy filesystem, where is the conventional place to put software you're working on?

Tags: linux, unix, conventions, directory-structure

This is an incredibly dumb question, but I don't know the answer. Apologies in advance.

I want to download a repo of someone else's code from GitHub to work on it. In a Unix-y filesystem, where is the most conventional place to put it?

I've been reading about [standard directory structure on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard#Directory_structure) and it looks like below `opt` might be the most appropriate place. Is that correct?

I'm using MacOS, so the alternative would be for me to create a custom folder under `/Users/me`, but I wondered if there was a conventional place for working on code within the standard Unix directories.

Comment: I've voted for a move to SuperUser. In any case: if it's something *you* are *working* on, you should put it in your home directory.

Comment: Most GNU programs have this configurable, and defaulted to `/usr/local/bin/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your usage plans.  If this is code you want to hack on, typically your home directory is the right place, since this is private to your unix user.  I personally make a 'dev' subdirectory and put code in there (mine or other people's, via github).

If you're looking to install this software system-wide, the answer varies slightly by the system.  /opt is a reasonable choice in most cases, as is /usr/local.

Comment: Thanks! Apologies for not posting this on SuperUser in the first place.